# Why is a.insert(0,0) much slower than a[0:0]=[0]?

Tags: python, performance

Using a list's `insert` function is much slower than achieving the same effect using slice assignment:

```
> python -m timeit -n 100000 -s "a=[]" "a.insert(0,0)"
100000 loops, best of 5: 19.2 usec per loop

> python -m timeit -n 100000 -s "a=[]" "a[0:0]=[0]"
100000 loops, best of 5: 6.78 usec per loop
```

(Note that `a=[]` is only the setup, so `a` starts empty but then grows to 100,000 elements.)

At first I thought maybe it's the attribute lookup or function call overhead or so, but inserting near the end shows that that's negligible:

```
> python -m timeit -n 100000 -s "a=[]" "a.insert(-1,0)"
100000 loops, best of 5: 79.1 nsec per loop
```

**Why is the presumably simpler dedicated "insert single element" function so much slower?**

I can also reproduce it [at repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ElasticExtrasmallAdmins):

```
from timeit import repeat

for _ in range(3):
  for stmt in 'a.insert(0,0)', 'a[0:0]=[0]', 'a.insert(-1,0)':
    t = min(repeat(stmt, 'a=[]', number=10**5))
    print('%.6f' % t, stmt)
  print()

# Example output:
#
# 4.803514 a.insert(0,0)
# 1.807832 a[0:0]=[0]
# 0.012533 a.insert(-1,0)
#
# 4.967313 a.insert(0,0)
# 1.821665 a[0:0]=[0]
# 0.012738 a.insert(-1,0)
#
# 5.694100 a.insert(0,0)
# 1.899940 a[0:0]=[0]
# 0.012664 a.insert(-1,0)
```

I use Python 3.8.1 32-bit on Windows 10 64-bit.
repl.it uses Python 3.8.1 64-bit on Linux 64-bit.

Comment: Interesting to note that `a=[]; a[0:0]=[0]` does the same as `a=[]; a[100:200]=[0]`

Comment: Is there any reason why you are testing this with just an empty list?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Well, I have to start with *something*. Note that it's empty only before the first insertion and grows to 100,000 elements during the benchmark.

Comment: @smac89 `a=[1,2,3];a[100:200]=[4]` is appending `4` to the end of the list `a` interesting.

Comment: Interesting note: Python 3.8 is much faster with `python3.8 -m timeit -n 100000 -s "a=[]" "a.insert(-1,0)"` Maype the [What’s New In Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) can help you get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @fabianegli: no, I can reproduce the issue, on Mac OSX, with 3.8.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I ment the 2x speedup of the insert method form Python 3.7 to 3.8. Admitedly not the question of your post. On MacOS.

Comment: @smac89 While that's true, it doesn't really have to do with the question and I fear it might mislead someone into thinking that I'm benchmarking `a=[]; a[0:0]=[0]` or that `a[0:0]=[0]` does the same as `a[100:200]=[0]`...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I think it's probably just that they forgot to use `memmove` in `list.insert`. If you take a look at the [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Objects/listobject.c#L311) `list.insert` uses to shift elements, you can see it's just a manual loop:

```
for (i = n; --i >= where; )
    items[i+1] = items[i];
```

while `list.__setitem__` on the slice assignment path [uses `memmove`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Objects/listobject.c#L716):

```
memmove(&item[ihigh+d], &item[ihigh],
    (k - ihigh)*sizeof(PyObject *));
```

`memmove` typically has a lot of optimization put into it, such as taking advantage of SSE/AVX instructions.

Comment: If the interpreter was built with `-O3` auto-vectorization enabled, that manual loop might compile efficiently.  But unless the compiler recognizes the loop as being a memmove and compiles it into an actual call to `memmove`, it can only take advantage of instruction-set extensions enabled at compile time.   (Fine if you're building your own with `-march=native`, not so much for distro binaries built with baseline).  And GCC won't unroll loops by default unless you use PGO (`-fprofile-generate` / run / `...-use`)

Comment: @PeterCordes Do I understand you correctly that if the compiler does compile it into an actual `memmove` call, that can then take advantage of all extensions present at execution time?

Comment: @HeapOverflow: Yes.  On GNU/Linux for example, glibc overloads dynamic linker symbol resolution with a function that picks the best hand-written asm version of memmove for this machine based on saved CPU-detection results.  (e.g. on x86, a glibc init function uses `cpuid`).  Same for several other mem / str functions.  So distros can compile with just `-O2` to make run-anywhere binaries, but at least have memcpy/memmove use an unrolled AVX loop loading/storing 32 bytes per instruction.  (Or even AVX512 on the few CPUs where that's a good idea; I think just Xeon Phi.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. So several `memmove` versions are included in the compiled program? When does the version get picked? At program start, or at every `memmove` execution, or at some other time?

Comment: @HeapOverflow: No, several `memmove` versions are sitting there in libc.so, the shared library.  For each function, dispatch happens once, during symbol resolution (early binding or on the first call with traditional lazy binding).  Like I said, it just overloads / hooks how dynamic linking happens, not by wrapping the function itself.  (specifically via GCC's ifunc mechanism: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove.c.html).  Related: for memset the usual choice on modern CPUs is `__memset_avx2_unaligned_erms` [see this Q&A](//stackoverflow.com/q/51614543)