# Is there a way to duplicate a list element without using loop in python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have to write a function `dup_elt(lst, pos=0)` that takes a list and expands it by duplicating the element in position `pos`, returning a new list.

Examples:

```
dup_elt([1, 2, 100, 8])      # [1, 1, 2, 100, 8]
dup_elt([1, 2, 100, 8], 2)   # [1, 2, 100, 100, 8]
dup_elt([1, 2, 100, 8], 10)  # [1, 2, 100, 8]
```

Assuming that `lst` is a non-empty list and `pos` is a non-negative `int`. If `lst[pos]` does not exist, `lst` should be returned unchanged.

Optional argument: The argument specification `pos=0` assigns the default value of 0 to pos if omitted from the function call.

I have done:

```
def dup_elt(lst,pos=0):
    return ([lst],(pos,pos))
```

However, that doesn't duplicate the list item.

Comment: This is pretty obviously a homework problem, and your attempt does not really show any effort to solve the problem. Enjoy your answers, but make sure to understand them. At some point your problems will become complicated enough that you won't be able to get trivial help for them.

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate two parts of the list that both contain the element to duplicate:

```
def dup_elt(lst, pos=0):
    return lst[:pos+1] + lst[pos:]
```

If you need to support negative indexes, you can write it like this:

```
def dup_elt(lst, pos=0):
    return lst[:pos+1 or None] + lst[pos:]
```

Comment: Ah, this is quite clever.

Answer (score 2):

Slice-assignment can handle this easily, actually. And you don't have to check if it is out of bounds because a slice that is out of bounds will return an empty list, and augmented assignment will do nothing!

```
def dup_elt(lst, pos=0):
    result = lst.copy()
    result[pos:pos + 1] *= 2
    return result
```

Alternatively, you can just use slicing, taking advantage that a slice out of bounds returns an empty list:

```
def dup_elt(lst, pos=0):
    return lst[:pos] + lst[pos:pos+1]*2 + lst[pos+1:]
```

Comment: `pos in range(len(lst))` is a bit overkill, no? `0 <= pos < len(lst)` wouldn't need a range object and seems more legible. Also, `value = lst[pos]` will check the same thing (except passing through negative indices).

Comment: @MadPhysicist `value = lst[pos]` would check but then might crash, no? Anyway, `result[pos : pos+1] *= 2` [also works](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwEETv@Yo5JhpKWxGkkC8pRcSmWgjJkmwO/fqYShH3OO/NMrTxO/jLjWIps10wZ7pbx9Il1qCQTKsGgXrRpuwYBpU0z0CbVH/5WFUMe@HcTTgZ9AfkHP3hCLGEuCtYa/TwLyuvx3OKq2dZkf4NGFuNTqOfvjOUKuUD), without checking by us.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode ah, yeah I would say that's better

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode. I used that crash in my answer. The `*=` trick is neat

Answer (score 2):

[`list.insert`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) exists:

```
def dup_elt(lst, pos=0):
    lst = lst.copy()
    try:
        lst.insert(pos, lst[pos]) 
    except IndexError:
        pass
    return lst
```

This should correctly support negative indices too.

Comment: I have a suspicion this may be the fastest. of course, setting up a meaningful profile would require some work that I'm not feeling like doing right now :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Slice assignment [can be faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60466436/16759116) than `insert`, though. Another issue: I think making a copy doesn't overallocate, so that then inserting a value (either way) will reallocate+move and thus cost extra time and space. Maybe it could be more efficient to insert into the original (hoping it's overallocated), then make a copy, then pop from the original, and then return the copy :-)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode. For a sufficiently small N, I would expect the overhead of the three operations to be more than the copy of N*4 (or *8) bytes.

Comment: @MadPhysicist While that question was inserting at the front and the culprit seems to be different ways to shift, I think I also benchmarked inserting at/near the end and slice assignments were also faster there, likely due to not having to load and call a method the way `insert` does.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode. I'm terrible at guessing timing results. I still don't understand why np.where is generally faster than np.nonzero. If you post an answer with some timing analysis I'd love to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with slicing:

```
def dup_elt(lst, pos=0):
    return lst[:pos] + [lst[pos]] + lst[pos:]
```

And now:

```
print(dup_elt([1, 2, 100, 8], 2))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 100, 100, 8]
```

Comment: Drop the +2, no? And check for out of bounds

Comment: @MadPhysicist Oh yes! that's a silly mistake from my end, thanks for catching it