# What is the fastest way to append unique integers to a list while keeping the list sorted?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, performance

I need to append values to an existing list one by one, while maintaining the following two conditions at all times:

- Every value in the list is unique
- The list is always sorted in ascending order

The values are all integers, and there is a huge amount of them (literally millions, no exaggeration), and the list is dynamically constructed, values are added or removed depending on a changing condition, and I really need a very efficient way to do this.

`sorted(set(lst))` doesn't qualify as a solution because first the list is not pre-existing and I need to mutate it after that, the solution isn't efficient by itself and to maintain the two above conditions I need to repeat the inefficient method after every mutation, which is impractical to do and would take an unimaginable amount of time to process millions of numbers.

One way to do it is to maintain a set with the same elements as the list, and do membership checking using the set and only add elements to the list if there aren't in the set, and add the same elements to both at the same time. This maintains uniqueness.

To maintain the order use binary search to calculate the insertion index required and insert the element at the index.

Example implementation I come up with without much thought:

```
from bisect import bisect

class Sorting_List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.unique = set()

    def add(self, n):
        if n in self.unique:
            return

        self.unique.add(n)
        if not self.data:
            self.data.append(n)
            return
        if n > self.data[-1]:
            self.data.append(n)
        elif n < self.data[0]:
            self.data.insert(0, n)
        elif len(self.data) == 2:
            self.data.insert(1, n)
        else:
            self.data.insert(bisect(self.data, n), n)
```

I am not satisfied with this solution, because I have to maintain a set, this isn't memory efficient and I don't think this is the most time efficient solution.

I have done some tests:

```
from timeit import timeit

def test(n):
    setup = f'''from bisect import bisect
from random import choice
c = choice(range({n//2}, {n}))
numbers = list(range({n}))'''
    linear = timeit('c in numbers', setup) / 1e6
    binary = timeit('bisect(numbers, c) - 1 == c ', setup) / 1e6
    return linear, binary
```

```
In [182]: [test(i) for i in range(1, 24)]
Out[182]:
[(3.1215199967846275e-08, 9.411800000816583e-08),
 (4.0730200009420514e-08, 9.4089699909091e-08),
 (5.392530001699925e-08, 1.0571250005159527e-07),
 (5.4071999969892203e-08, 1.111615999834612e-07),
 (5.495569994673133e-08, 1.3055420003365725e-07),
 (7.999380002729595e-08, 1.2215890001971274e-07),
 (6.739119999110698e-08, 1.1633279989473522e-07),
 (1.1775600002147258e-07, 1.2142769992351532e-07),
 (9.138470003381372e-08, 1.1602859990671277e-07),
 (1.212503999704495e-07, 1.2919300002977253e-07),
 (1.4093979995232076e-07, 1.1543070001062005e-07),
 (1.3911779993213713e-07, 1.1900339997373521e-07),
 (1.641304000513628e-07, 1.2721199996303767e-07),
 (2.2550319996662438e-07, 1.3572790008038284e-07),
 (2.0048839994706214e-07, 1.2690539995674044e-07),
 (2.0169020001776515e-07, 1.3345349999144673e-07),
 (1.482249000109732e-07, 1.2819399998988957e-07),
 (1.777580000925809e-07, 1.2856919993646443e-07),
 (1.5940839995164425e-07, 1.2710969999898224e-07),
 (2.772621000185609e-07, 1.4048079994972795e-07),
 (2.014727999921888e-07, 1.4225799997802823e-07),
 (2.851358000189066e-07, 1.3718699989840387e-07),
 (2.607858000556007e-07, 1.4413580007385463e-07)]
```

So the membership checking of lists is done using a linear search, by iterating through the list one by one and perform equality checking, this is inefficient but beats binary search for small number of elements (n <= 12) and is much slower for larger amounts.

```
In [183]: test(256)
Out[183]: (2.5505281999940053e-06, 1.7594210000243037e-07)
```

And `set` membership checking is faster than binary search, which is much faster than linear search:

```
In [188]: lst = list(range(256))

In [189]: s = set(lst)

In [190]: %timeit 199 in s
42.5 ns ± 0.946 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)

In [191]: %timeit bisect(lst, 199)
159 ns ± 1.38 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)

In [192]: %timeit 199 in lst
2.53 µs ± 31.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

How can we devise a faster method?

---

I am well aware that Python `set`s are unordered, and sorting `set`s yields `list`s. But perhaps there are some external libraries that provide ordered sets, if there are then I am not aware of them and I haven't used them.

Solutions using such ordered sets are welcome so long as they are performant, but I am not asking for recommendations so please don't close the question for that reason.

Nevertheless ordered sets only fulfill the first criterium, only uniqueness is maintained, and I need the orderedness to be maintained as well.

`list` here is just terminology, in plain Python `list` is the only ordered mutable sequence. Other data types are welcome.

[About SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76599694/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-append-unique-integers-to-a-list-while-keeping-the-li#comment135054513_76599694), I haven't tested in-memory transient databases yet, but for a local [HDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive) based database, the I/O delay is many milliseconds which is unacceptable.

---

I have just performed yet another test:

```
In [243]: numbers = random.choices(range(4294967295), k=1048576)

In [244]: sl = Sorting_List()

In [245]: ss = SortedSet()

In [246]: %timeit for i in numbers: ss.add(i)
306 ms ± 8.55 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [247]: %timeit for i in numbers: sl.add(i)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
...

In [248]: sls = SortedList()

In [249]: s = set()

In [250]: %%timeit
     ...: for i in numbers:
     ...:     if i not in s:
     ...:         sls.add(i)
     ...:         s.add(i)
145 ms ± 3.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [251]: len(numbers)
Out[251]: 1048576
```

It seems my custom implementation is at least as performant as `SortedSet` for reasonable amount of data, I need much more efficient methods.

For a million elements my method becomes very inefficient indeed, while `SortedSet` and `SortedList` both keep being competent.

And now it seems a `SortedList` plus a `set` for membership checking is the most time efficient method, but obviously not very memory efficient, just as my custom implementation. But my custom implementation seems to outperform `SortedSet` which seems to be memory efficient.

---

Testing `SortedList` by adding 2^20 elements one by one, while keeping the elements unique by doing membership checking using the container itself:

```
In [252]: sls = SortedList()

In [253]: %%timeit
     ...: for i in numbers:
     ...:     if i not in sls:
     ...:         sls.add(i)
1.93 s ± 16.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

(`numbers` is defined above)

The test clearly shows `SortedList` membership checking is slow, as suspected, it uses linear search.

Comment: Are you bound to python or would you considere dropping down to C? You could write a python-extention in C and implemt your custom data type there, similar to how numpy implemtens its custom data types to allow for faster operations.

Comment: Why do you want a list instead of a sorted set?

Comment: And why even bother benchmarking such small lists when you really want much larger ones? Those results might be misleading.

Comment: I suspect *finding* an element in a large sorted list isn't the problem anyway, inserting or removing is probably more costly (assuming with "list" you mean one of type `list`).

Comment: I would suggest trying to put the list into an in memory SQLite table.  In the end the same as your Python solutions, but pushed down to C.  Note that SQLite comes with Python, so is available everywhere with no further installation.

Comment: @btilly I don't have much experience with using that, but it sounds bulky. Is it more efficient than `sortedcontainers.SortedSet`?

Comment: You'll want to look at balanced binary search trees - insertion and removal of elements can be done in O(log_2 n) and the balancing ensures you're always searching in O(log_2 n) too.

Comment: @KellyBundy I think there is a good chance it is more efficient, but would have to benchmark.  It is basically down to, "is the overhead of marshalling between very different representations paid for by how efficiently SQLite was implemented in C?

Comment: Not sure I understand how you can keep a list sorted by appending things to the end - surely you'd need to insert? If you append, the items will necessarily be in the order of arrival rather than any sorted order. #ConfusedOfCheltenham

Comment: The first two are special cases, if a number is larger than the last number in the sorted list or the first number, because the list is sorted, they must be the largest and smallest numbers respectively, so putting the element at the end or the beginning will keep the list sorted, this is supposed to skip binary search, because it doesn't short circuit in the special cases.

Comment: Ok, now the benchmark looks alright. Could you try one more version, with only `SortedList`, without `set` (using `if i not in sls:` instead)? Btw I think this evaluation part would better be an answer instead of part of the question.

Comment: I think you reimplemented `bisect.insort` (besides checking for uniqueness which it doesn't do).

Comment: *"SortedList implements a linear search instead of binary search for membership"* - No, it does use binary search. Linear search would be **much** slower than that.

Comment: Note that "`SortedList` plus a `set`" which you tested is exactly how `SortedSet` is implemented.

Comment: *"SortedSet uses binary search for membership"* - No it doesn't. It just does a membership test with its internal set.

Comment: *"SortedList membership checking is slow, as suspected, it uses linear search"* - No, like I already said, it does use binary search and linear search would be **much** slower than that.

Comment: I thought if we're using bisect to find the position, why not ditch the set and just use bisect_left to get an index. Check the index for equality before inserting. But it's testing out a smidge slower than just maintaining a set for metadata, much to my surprise. Also note that (unless I'm benchmarking it wrong) a simple "sorted(set(data))" crushes all the iterative solutions, but that doesn't have the iterative capability you asked for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like data rather than guessing so I profiled the approaches suggested by @Kelly Bundy

```
from bisect import bisect
from sortedcontainers import SortedList, SortedSet


class Sorting_List:
    # The Original
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.unique = set()

    def add(self, n):
        if n in self.unique:
            return

        self.unique.add(n)
        if not self.data:
            self.data.append(n)
            return
        if n > self.data[-1]:
            self.data.append(n)
        elif n < self.data[0]:
            self.data.insert(0, n)
        elif len(self.data) == 2:
            self.data.insert(1, n)
        else:
            self.data.insert(bisect(self.data, n), n)


class Sorting_List_Kelly:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.unique = set()

    def add(self, n):
        if n in self.unique:
            return
        self.unique.add(n)
        self.data[bisect(self.data, n) : 0] = (n,)


class SortedListWrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = SortedList()
        self.unique = set()

    def add(self, n):
        if n in self.unique:
            return
        self.unique.add(n)
        self.data.add(n)
```

```
import random

from performance_measurement import run_performance_comparison


def original(values):
    x = Sorting_List()
    for value in values:
        x.add(value)
    return x.data


def kelly(values):
    x = Sorting_List_Kelly()
    for value in values:
        x.add(value)
    return x.data


def sortedset(values):
    x = SortedSet()
    for value in values:
        x.add(value)
    return x


def sortedlist(values):
    x = SortedListWrapper()
    for value in values:
        x.add(value)
    return x


def generate_lists(N):
    return [random.sample(range(N), N)]


data_size = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000]

approaches = [original, kelly, sortedset, sortedlist]

run_performance_comparison(approaches, data_size, setup=generate_lists)
```

[image]

Especially for small problem instances @Kelly Bundy's improved approach outperforms `SortedList` with a wrapper and `SortedSet` from `sortedcontainers`.

[image]

Profiling code:

```
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from typing import List, Dict, Callable

from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def data_provider(data_size, setup=lambda N: N, teardown=lambda: None):
    data = setup(data_size)
    yield data
    teardown()


def run_performance_comparison(approaches: List[Callable],
                               data_size: List[int],
                               setup=lambda N: N,
                               teardown=lambda: None,
                               number_of_repetitions=5, title='N'):
    approach_times: Dict[Callable, List[float]] = {approach: [] for approach in approaches}

    for N in data_size:
        with data_provider(N, setup, teardown) as data:
            for approach in approaches:
                approach_time = timeit.timeit(lambda: approach(*data), number=number_of_repetitions)
                approach_times[approach].append(approach_time)

    for approach in approaches:
        plt.plot(data_size, approach_times[approach], label=approach.__name__)

    plt.xlabel(title)
    plt.ylabel('Execution Time (seconds)')
    plt.title('Performance Comparison')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like a good use case for [`SortedSet`](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedset.html) from the popular and performance-oriented `sortedcontainers` library. It does use a set and a more complicated list structure than a bare `list`, so it does take more memory. But it does that to be fast.

If you don't need set operations and are ok with doing a membership check yourself before inserting a value (i.e., `if x not in lst: lst.add(x)`), then [`SortedList`](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html) might be better.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting *sortedcontainers*. Had never heard of it previously. Looks very useful

Comment: @DarkKnight Yeah I used it a few times, I think mostly for `algorithm` questions here on SO and at LeetCode (one of just a few extra libraries they installed for Python). It's fairly popular, 3k stars [on GitHub](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-sortedcontainers). There's also [sortedcollections](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcollections/) with a few other data types, but it's less popular and I think I only used it once or twice.

Comment: @DarkKnight Also note my [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76599694/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-append-unique-integers-to-a-list-while-keeping-the-li/76600172?noredirect=1#comment135055571_76600172) under the other answer (can't notify you there now that you deleted your comment).

Comment: Sorry for deleting. I thought I'd deleted it before you responded. I realised too late that it was a nonsensical comment

Comment: @DarkKnight I don't think it was nonsensical :-). Partly because you asked about `insort_left` instead of `list.insert` (there could be a significant difference) and partly because I hadn't broken down the impacts of my two optimizations.

Comment: @DarkKnight Interestingly, `insort(self.data, n)` is actually even noticeably *slower* than bisect+insert. Gotta be due to the extra key check, storing/loading the index `lo`, and extra parameters it uses, and the overhead of calling another function. [Code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9e335860188229a7985fe9a8b72ee62c684aa9eb/Lib/bisect.py#L4-L16).

Comment: @KellyBundy `insort` is actually implemented in C (see line 102 in your link), so it's surprising that it's slower.

Comment: @interjay Ah, right, I should've checked that. It still does those extra things, but at C level that's less significant, and the the Python overhead of bisect+insert could be larger. But, [1.1 s for bisect+insert and 1.3 s for insort](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVFdasMwDGavPoXe6ow0bbP0J4WepJSQJvZihu3gqJQydpLB6Mt2qJ1mcu1A91iDsSV_P5L1-dNfsLPmev0-oZxufp--pLMajmoQDYLSvXUYoxSUGShkMetq01rNbnhUWoxof2esFRLOCruKSMIhT7YMaLU11rCD_eEWSevAkCyYkz4KNwTMiMsiNdhzn0rBJH7_17eP60fWqMlYRBA39JU1nVWNGDiFr4IXeVmUq3VeLsn_bbeYF5vlejWbLebE9TbS2-zvOk7vyzvAM7wEdyQL_0U8CSXGs3fKIJeT9_AGUwJus1x-TFKQWVWZWouqSsKY4rTGqf0B).

Comment: @KellyBundy Running that same code on my machine, `insort` is consistently about 1% faster. I don't understand the results on that site.

Comment: @interjay What Python version are you using? That site uses 3.11.4.

Comment: I used version 3.11.3. I also tried your slice version and it was twice as fast.

Answer (score 2):

Some notes about yours, here it is again for easier comparison (and in case you edit it :-):

```
class Sorting_List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.unique = set()
    
    def add(self, n):
        if n in self.unique:
            return

        self.unique.add(n)
        if not self.data:
            self.data.append(n)
            return
        if n > self.data[-1]:
            self.data.append(n)
        elif n < self.data[0]:
            self.data.insert(0, n)
        elif len(self.data) == 2:
            self.data.insert(1, n)
        else:
            self.data.insert(bisect(self.data, n), n)
```

And my optimized version:

```
class Sorting_List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.unique = set()
    
    def add(self, n):
        if n in self.unique:
            return
        self.unique.add(n)
        self.data[bisect(self.data, n) : 0] = n,
```

Adding `random.choices(range(4294967295), k=1048576//10)` one at a time, I get ~1.2 seconds with yours and ~0.7 seconds with mine.

You optimize rare cases at the expense of all other cases which have to go through all those optimization checks. That's a bad idea, makes it slower overall. Well, if `n > self.data[-1]` is common with your actual data (it isn't with your benchmark data), then that optimization might be worth doing. But especially the `not self.data` and `len(self.data) == 2` are really just a waste of time and code.

Also, your data is large enough that it likely benefits from using slice assignments instead of calling `insert`, as that's implemented differently and in my experience is faster for such large cases. See [Why is a.insert(0,0) much slower than a[0:0]=[0]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60466436/12671057)

Comment: @DarkKnight Depends on what you mean with "known" :-). It's known *to me*, on the devices I've tried it on, for large enough data (I think `list.insert` is still faster when it needs to shift just a few thousand items). In this case, the improvement from 1.2 to 0.7 seconds is almost entirely thanks to the slice assignment. Last I checked, `insort` and `insort_left` use `list.insert` and thus are similarly slow for large enough data. It won't be modified to use the different way, as inserting in a huge list is unusual and bad anyway, something like `SortedList` should be used instead.

Comment: (In other words, insert/insort won't be modified to use the different shifting way for the same *"don't optimize rare cases at the expense of the common cases"* reason that I talked about.)

Comment: Unless self.unique is used elsewhere, you could do without it by checking if the item at the insertion index (`i = bisect(self.data, n)`) already contains the number `if n in self.data[i:i+1]: return`.  No significative performance loss, unless duplicates are frequent, but would use a bit less memory.

Comment: @AlainT. Right. It looks similarly fast, and actually uses *a lot* less memory, since sets take ~5x more space than lists (due to storing not just a reference to each element but also its hash, and overallocating much more than lists). I might add that with some analysis later, but have busy days ahead.

Comment: @AlainT. Oh and another idea, also space-saving: Using an `array`. Could drop memory from 8+32 bytes per element to 4 bytes. Don't know about speed, though, and whether `bisect` works on it...

Comment: @AlainT. Small correction: you need to use `bisect_left` (or check `data[i-1]`).

Comment: Indeed, I forgot I had changed it in my import statement when I tested it which was a rather sloppy way of doing it I admit (`from bisect import bisect_left as bisect`)