# lists vs python arrays. specifically the insert method

Tags: python, arrays, list, algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to solve the [following problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-of-smaller-numbers-after-self/description/) in leetcode.

> Given an integer array nums, return an integer array counts where counts[i] is the number of smaller elements to the right of nums[i]

The following solution rocks (1300 ms):

```
import bisect
import array

class Solution:
    def countSmaller(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        ns = array.array('h')
        # ns = list()
        ans = [0] * len(nums)
        for i in range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1):
            x = nums[i]
            l = bisect.bisect_left(ns, x)
            ans[i] = l
            ns.insert(l, x)
        return ans
```

The following solution sucks (5000ms):

```
import bisect
import array

class Solution:
    def countSmaller(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        # ns = array.array('h')
        ns = list()
        ans = [0] * len(nums)
        for i in range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1):
            x = nums[i]
            l = bisect.bisect_left(ns, x)
            ans[i] = l
            ns.insert(l, x)
        return ans
```

The only difference is the usage of lists (sucks) vs python arrays (rocks)

If the operation I am doing repeatedly is `.insert` then I don't think any of the benefits arising from the fact that python arrays are static would come into play. The array would have to be reallocated every time I increase the size of the array by inserting a value (correct?). At least lists allocate dynamically and at the very least should match the performance of arrays.

questions:

1. The algorithms are O(n^2) for the arrays, right? I am running an insert for every element in the nums
2. Is the performance gain only because of fast indexing in arrays because they have dtype specified? Or, is there any other reason?
3. Please also help me correct any wrong understanding I might have asserted in the question

Comment: Have you profiled these or disassembled them?

Comment: array.insert memmove()'s everything after the insertion point while list.insert separately moves each item from the end of the list back to the insertion point forward a slot. I didn't profile that but it sounds slower to me. :) (edit: the list is also a bunch of probably 64-bit pointers and your array is a bunch of probably 32-bit shorts, so that's twice as much stuff to move.)

Comment: Yes, the worst case time complexity is O(n²). A better solution could achieve runtime O(n log n).

Comment: I highly doubt that every insertion will cause a reallocation. I know no dynamic array implementation which doesn't grow arrays exponentially (which gives you amortized constant time append at the cost of leaving half the memory unused in the worst case).

Comment: @Luatic Yes, my implementation ran in nlogn time. However, the test cases on leetcode are not large arrays and the O(n2) solution is giving lesser time. Python arrays are not dynamic arrays. Lists are

Comment: @MichaelRuth - No I have not. I will do it and keep the results posted

Comment: @Luatic - I think I was wrong. Python arrays are also dynamic. Just the dtypes are constrained.

Comment: @Wooble - "array.insert memmove()'s everything after the insertion point while list.insert separately moves each item from the end of the list back to the insertion point forward a slot." - The two sound the same to me. What is the difference?

Comment: @Wooble even worse, due to Python's dynamic typing, the list may be a bunch of tagged unions (unless some tricks like NaN boxing are used or everything is heap allocated). If they are aligned to 64-bit boundaries, each of these tagged unions will take 128 bit (64 bit tag + 64 bit value). That would be four times as much stuff to move, which could roughly explain the time difference.

Comment: @figs_and_nuts If you take a look at the source code in `Objects/listobject.c`, you will find that insertion uses a naive loop to move elements: `for (i = n; --i >= where; ) items[i+1] = items[i];`. This may be less efficient than `memmove`, which could for example be implemented more efficiently using SIMD vector instructions or other low level tricks.

Comment: @Wooble It looks like compilers are smart enough to turn the explicit loop into a `memmove`. See [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xr79fvYrr). The tagged union explanation seems most plausible to me currently.

Comment: @Wooble Nevermind the tagged unions, it seems my theory doesn't explain it (shouldn't have extrapolated from Lua); Python seems to heap-allocate everything, including floats and ints. I think the explanation is that [signed shorts (`h`) may be only 16, not 32 bit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), hence 64/16 = 4 and it's 4 times slower, as is expected.

Answer (score 3):

Both are O(n^2). Almost all time is spent for the insertions, moving all data after the insertion point to make room for the value to be inserted.

The array is faster because:

1. It has less memory to move: 2 bytes per element vs 8 bytes per element, as you can tell with `print(sys.getsizeof(ns))` for a sufficiently large case (e.g., use 100000 elements and you'll see ~200000 and ~800000 bytes, respectively).
2. It uses `memmove`, while `list.insert` [moves with a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60466436/12671057) that's slower than `memmove` for moving large amounts.

If you change the array to `array.array('l')`, it uses 8 bytes per element as well. And if you insert into the list with `ns[l:l] = x,`, then it uses `memmove` as well. And then both solutions take about the same time, around 2600 ms.