# Finding the minimum absolute difference between elements minimum of k distance apart

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have a problem I encountered I was unable to solve.

Given a distance of k, and an array of positive integers nums, find the minimum absolute difference between elements of numbers that are at least k indices apart.

I don't think sorting is a solution since we need to also consider the position of the indices.

I discovered a solution in O(n^2) and a solution in O(n * (max(numbers)-min(numbers)) but they are not efficient enough. The boundary on each number and the length of nums are both very high.

How would I solve this more efficiently?

For reference, my O(n^2) solution is here:

```
def minimum_difference_with_k(nums, k):
    ans = float('inf')

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        for j in range(k + i, len(nums)):
            ans = min(ans, abs(nums[i] - nums[j]))

    return ans
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What do "efficient enough" and "very high" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable in `O(n log(n))` if you have a sorted container that lets you find neighbors. What you do is keep adding in the value `k` back, then seeing what is closest to the current value. The insert and search are both `O(log(n))`, and you do it `O(n)` times.

Unfortunately Python doesn't include that kind of sorted container in the standard library.

But it does include `sqlite3` which has indexes that can do this for us. So, as absurd as it looks:

```
import sqlite3

def closest_apart(values, k):
    if len(values) < k:
        return None

    con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE trailing_values (value int)")
    cursor.execute("CREATE INDEX tv ON trailing_values (value)")

    best = max(values) - min(values)
    for i in range(k, len(values)):
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO trailing_values VALUES (?)", (values[i-k],))

        res = cursor.execute("SELECT min(value) - ? FROM trailing_values WHERE ? < value", (values[i], values[i]))
        out = res.fetchone()[0]
        if out is not None and out < best:
            best = out

        res = cursor.execute("SELECT ? - max(value) FROM trailing_values WHERE value < ?", (values[i], values[i]))
        out = res.fetchone()[0]
        if out is not None and out < best:
            best = out
    return best
```

This will break if you go outside of the 8 byte integer range that `sqlite3` provides. For the theoretically general solution you'd have to get a binary tree. Many pip packages exist for that, but the first couple I looked at don't include finding the nearest neighbors. I could easily write that, but the `sqlite3` trick probably suffices for you.

Comment: Have you tried `sortedcontainers.SortedList` and its bisect methods? A sorted pure Python list with Python's `bisect` functions might also be fast enough. But that SQLite trick is neat.

Comment: Looks like SQLite becomes faster than a sorted list at around 80000 elements.

Comment: @KellyBundy I didn't see what I was looking for in `sortedcontainers.SortedList`. But looking more closely at bisect, it should be faster. I'm surprised that the sorted list holds up that well.

Comment: Well, insertion takes linear time, but it's pretty much just a memmove, very low-level and fast. Would love to see a plot comparing speeds of all three ways for random data up to length 100000 or so. Especially since I have no experience/feeling of SQLite speeds. I imagine very few people do. This might be the first time I've ever even seen it being used for an algorithmic task like this.

Comment: Oh, in case you or someone else does benchmark it with a sorted ordinary list: I think slice assignment is still [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60466436/12671057) for inserting into such long lists.

Comment: Btw the reason I measured this a bit at all was to convince me that SQLite is indeed smart enough to execute those queries efficiently (it seems to, doubling the input length made your function take only about twice as long).

Comment: Is there some documentation somewhere about how smart SQLite is, what queries it does efficiently? I just tried `cursor.execute("SELECT min(abs(value - ?)) FROM trailing_values", (values[i],))` and it was slow (looks like linear time).

Comment: @KellyBundy https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html is a good place to start. In this case an index is like a btree, and if it can replace a WHERE condition with an index lookup, it does.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it in `O(n log(n))` if you've installed `sortedcontainers`.

Note that this also works for very big integers, rationals, and floating point. But it is slower than `sqlite3`.

```
import sortedcontainers

def neighbors (sorted_list, value):
    i = sorted_list.bisect_left(value)
    if 0 < i:
        yield sorted_list[i-1]
    if i < len(sorted_list):
        yield sorted_list[i]

def closest_apart (values, k):
    if len(values) < k:
        return None

    before = sortedcontainers.SortedList()
    best = abs(values[0] - values[k])
    for i in range(k, len(values)):
        before.add(values[i-k])
        for neighbor in neighbors(before, values[i]):
            if abs(values[i] - neighbor) < best:
                best = abs(values[i] - neighbor)
    return best
```

And here is `O(n log^2(n))`. Worse asymptotically, but it beats sqlite3 in benchmarks.

The slab idea is based on the implementation of [BigTable](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf).

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def slab_neighbors(slabs, value):
    for slab in slabs:
        i = bisect_left(slab, value)
        if 0 < i:
            yield slab[i-1]
        if i < len(slab):
            yield slab[i]

def btilly_slabs(nums, k):
    if len(nums) < k:
        return None

    best = abs(nums[0] - nums[k])
    slabs = [[]]
    for i in range(k, len(nums)):
        value = nums[i-k]
        slabs[-1][bisect_left(slabs[-1], value) : 0] = [value]

        value = nums[i]
        for neighbor in slab_neighbors(slabs, value):
            if abs(value - neighbor) < best:
                best = abs(value - neighbor)

        # Slab management.
        while 1 < len(slabs) and len(slabs[-2]) <= len(slabs[-1]):
            s1 = slabs.pop()
            s2 = slabs.pop()
            slabs.append(list(sorted(s1+s2)))
        if 2000 < len(slabs[-1]):
            slabs.append([])

    return best
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers! It helped me a lot and I was able to create a solution based on yours with a heap.

Answer (score 0):

Same algorithm as [btilly's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76972472/12671057), but keeping the "trailing" values in a sorted list `xs`:

```
from bisect import bisect, bisect_left

def minimum_difference_with_k(nums, k):
    xs = []
    return min(
        abs(x - y)
        for x, y in zip(nums, nums[k:])
        for xs[bisect(xs, x) : 0] in [(x,)]
        for i in [bisect_left(xs, y)]
        for x in xs[i and i-1 : i+1]
    )
```

Benchmark with 100000 random numbers and k=1000, three test cases, showing solution results and runtimes in seconds:

```
181731 0.87 btilly_sqlite
181731 0.8 Kelly_sorted_list

42493 1.05 btilly_sqlite
42493 0.79 Kelly_sorted_list

34909 0.89 btilly_sqlite
34909 0.74 Kelly_sorted_list

Python: 3.11.4 (main, Jun 24 2023, 10:18:04) [GCC 13.1.1 20230429]
```

With 200000 numbers:

```
36916 2.14 btilly_sqlite
36916 3.2 Kelly_sorted_list

7955 1.87 btilly_sqlite
7955 2.89 Kelly_sorted_list

46459 1.89 btilly_sqlite
46459 2.81 Kelly_sorted_list
```

My runtime is quadratic due to the insertions into the sorted list taking linear time, but that's relatively fast linear time, so it's still competitive with such large inputs.

Benchmark code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=xVXNjtMwEL5xyFOMemm8pFHKCglFW1XLEsSK0kXd8iOVKOqPs1hNnBI7qwTEk3DZCzwUT8PYTpukK1bcyKH1jMfj7xt_Hv_4tavk54zf3f0sZDx49vuRxdJdlksQXxIm6enezJd8k6VWnGcpSJZSqP1qbLwrJuha7v3Gcur_KKGxPGSuhGVZGxrDa5okVSTQSTdRwoS0eZEKB7bEtwC_UsAIFqEe51QWOYeUcVvb6luuhF3CACpycMVZDqUDFTAOX9muTqh-F1s_PIoTCwPPLjGmJOCDF6qFi0UZhp1Qpt0tMnpJRbpRpYrCrAywWsAGQ8zIHg9NEKlJryTTrHV97dtlUtAWZRZDQnntJnAGW_-wRV2CacappZ3rjGOB6pNy0eKKTM9PaZrlld8zdNdFjiXGQAxwjWG3Z1xa0nWBWHoXs-B8HsD8_PkkAJkvWcL4TWSwgMGEDCXpPbj8cvoi-AjyFq6mf0miEugMKyokAkuX5YHxQB9xbVmd-qMGb6i9ddoVIk15juFcTq-D2RzhzK_u4Xh_PnkXXIM9Jj2nBoXHNtiGDqmhmYIrAR7nvQ4mwcW8gakwj-Hl7OrNvW0-vApmAU6ejUB72puFDhyGpBFmVqiK4M5uTOUarya1ycJrdIYCUSFMAM-k1oIWm_Kd6Xo2BWlVGKf_kdZYncD-PMhDtIwekNr4v9Jq3QzlxVumBMOVYIaeF3me58ATMzA5djlq2I7739Tl-f6J9xuZRY3MTlvKUu1Dodc90EX0bE2FbeKG3snJ8CnBGzziDd0thg_VllanQcQqf6cBOPebYJep9DCV6rI26fhrFoeO6UCeFXxjm1A8RKl4ozt2o4gvUxpFTQKzGJVuBv23-hHw-45qzu4tzQXLODFPQv0y7F-IPw)):

```py
import sqlite3
import random
from time import time
from bisect import bisect, bisect_left
import sys


def Kelly_sorted_list(nums, k):
    xs = []
    return min(
        abs(x - y)
        for x, y in zip(nums, nums[k:])
        for xs[bisect(xs, x) : 0] in [[x]]
        for i in [bisect_left(xs, y)]
        for x in xs[i and i-1 : i+1]
    )


def btilly_sqlite(values, k):
    if len(values) < k:
        return None

    con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE trailing_values (value int)")
    cursor.execute("CREATE INDEX tv ON trailing_values (value)")

    best = max(values) - min(values)
    for i in range(k, len(values)):
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO trailing_values VALUES (?)", (values[i-k],))

        res = cursor.execute("SELECT min(value) - ? FROM trailing_values WHERE ? <= value", (values[i], values[i]))
        out = res.fetchone()[0]
        if out is not None and out < best:
            best = out

        res = cursor.execute("SELECT ? - max(value) FROM trailing_values WHERE value <= ?", (values[i], values[i]))
        out = res.fetchone()[0]
        if out is not None and out < best:
            best = out
    return best


for n in 100_000, 200_000:
    print(f'{n = }\n')
    for _ in range(3):
        nums = random.choices(range(10**15), k=n)
        k = 1_000

        for f in btilly_sqlite, Kelly_sorted_list:
            t0 = time()
            print(f(nums, k), round(time() - t0, 2), f.__name__)
        print()

print('Python:', sys.version)
```

Comment: I added two other solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76979584/585411. The `sortedcontainers` approach is slower than `sqlite3`. The slab approach is faster but theoretically will scale more poorly for very large numbers.

Comment: Under pypy, all speed up. But `sortedcontainers` and slabs both are now 3x as fast as `sqlite3`. Your approach wound up the slowest. (Makes sense, the performance bottleneck was already in well-optimized C.)

Comment: @btilly Yep, agrees with my own benchmarks (just CPython). Was hoping for better performance of sortedcontainers.